# Использование одной переменной в нескольких функциях

Tags: python, global-variables

Делаю калькулятор. Программа работала. Решил упростить и вынести счёт значения (`eval`) в отдельную функцию. Появилась ошибка:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment

Пример кода:

```
def calc():
    try:
        result = eval(calc_entry.get())
        calc_entry.delete(0, 1000)
    except:
        messagebox.showerror('Ошибка!', 'Проверьте введённые данные')

def act(key):
    if key == '=':
        calc()
        calc_entry.insert(END, str(result))
```

Comment: В данном случае лучше вернуть переменную `result` из функции `calc`.

Comment: Можно подробней, я только осваиваю python.

Comment: Получилось. Добавил global в обоих функциях.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте global, не нужно умножать количество говнокода во вселенной. Используйте ключевое слово return чтобы вернуть значение из функции. Подробности здесь: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/vse-o-funkciyax-i-ix-argumentax.html

Comment: код в вопросе не может указанную ошибку вывести.¶ В сторону: не используйте пустые `except:` — это может ошибки скрывать.

Comment: про except знаю, написал пустой для сокращения кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что надо в конец блока try в функции calc вернуть значение result путем инструкции:

```
return result
```

и изменить строку в act():

```
calc()
```

на:

```
result = calc()
```

Comment: огромное спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, Александр Завалишин!

Comment: Я очень надеюсь, что мой ответ вам пригодился в решении задачи ;)